# I wanted to make a bat file which will find the total RAM of my pc and install software according to it

Tags: batch-file

I have to deploy antivirus to any PC there is no SCCM or AD, so I had to make a batch file that will automatically compare RAM and install antivirus according to the RAM. There are more PC with 2GB RAM and that PC won't support Intercept X. I have tested this bat file on two pcs one with 4 GB RAM and it did install intercept X and I checked the same script on PC with 2GB RAM, but in that PC it again installed intercept X, I need to install the only antivirus in case of 2 GB RAM.

code:

```
    @echo off

    SET NEWLINE=^& echo.

    ECHO %NEWLINE%^ >>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

    ECHO %NEWLINE%^172.31.254.222 sophos>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts


    for /f "tokens=2* delims=:" %%a in ('systeminfo ^| findstr /I /C:"Total Physical Memory"') do set RAM=%%a

    IF RAM GTR 2048 GOTO InterceptX

    IF RAM LSS 2048 GOTO Endpoint

  :InterceptX
   \\172.31.254.222\setup\SophosSetup.exe --products=intercept --messagerelays=172.31.254.222:8190

  :Endpoint 
   \\172.31.254.222\setup\SophosSetup.exe --products=antivirus --messagerelays=172.31.254.222:8190
   popd
```

Comment: Variables are referenced with percent symbols.  `IF %RAM% GTR 2048 GOTO InterceptX`. Regardless of that, your comparison will still not work because the value of ram is formatted like this. `16,198 MB`. The value of ram has to be an integer for the comparision to work.

Comment: I should also note that if you run `InterceptX` it will still execute the `:ENDPOINT` because you don't have a  branch to skip over it.  Would be better if you just did an `IF..ELSE` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would offer the following solution, it leverages [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) to retrieve the total physical RAM, instead of loading the extremely slow `systeminfo.exe`.

I have additionally added a check to close the script if it is not running elevated. *(this will be required for writing to the `hosts` file)*

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
"%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" Query HKU\S-1-5-19 1>NUL 2>&1 || GoTo :EOF
Set "_S=172.31.254.222"
(Echo(&Echo %_S% sophos)>>"%__APPDIR__%drivers\etc\hosts"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('^""%__APPDIR__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"^
 -NoProfile "(GWMI Win32_PhysicalMemory|Measure Capacity -Sum).Sum/1MB"^"'
) Do Set "MBRAM=%%A"
If %MBRAM% GEq 2048 (Set "_P=intercept") Else Set "_P=antivirus"
"\\%_S%\setup\SophosSetup.exe" --products=%_P% --messagerelays=%_S%:8190
```